# how to pass data table (an object) from javascript file to node js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, ejs

I have an HTML page that show a table contains student names and some information about them and the page also contains of some controls to control this table so I did a save button to save this table
and I name this table SIT as an object in javascript code (which is related to the page)

I managed to save this table Manually in mongo
and sent it back to the page with node js

```
app.get('/table',function(req,res){
tbl.find ({}, "tableData", function(err, resualt) {
    if (err) {
        console.log (err)
    } else {
        var SIT = {}
        if (resualt.length != 0) { SIT = resualt[resualt.length-1].tableData }
        res.render("table", {table: SIT})
    }
})
```

now I want to pass this object to Nodejs to save it with mongo

(I use express and ejs template)

Answer (score -1):

You need to get a reference to your database connection to be able to save to the database from your Node server. One popular package you can add to your project to help with this is called [Mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/). You can look at their documentation to see how you can do different things with your mongoose database using Javascript in your Node server. Let me know if this doesn't answer your question.

Comment: They already have a library for accessing their database. We can see it being used in the question.

Comment: I actually use mongoose package
all i want to pass SIT the data table from javascipt file to node js to save it in mongo
how can i pass this table